# Having issue in outlook for newsletter

Tags: outlook, newsletter, spacing

I have problem for extra spacing in outlook and you can see on attached image i highlighted in red color. I used p for this image

the code is for this image

```
<p style=" width:125; height:125; margin:0px; padding:0px 10px 0px 10px; float:right; line-height:125px; "><img src="http://hmsdesignz.com/newsletter/6of6/images/icon.jpg" alt="" width="125" height="125" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" align="right"  style="display:block;"/></p>
```

[image]!

Please advice me how can I remove this extra spacing

Answer (score 0):

Need more of the code to see how it is interacting with the html around it.

You are using a `<p>` tag, which I'd avoid. The image should be in a table cell by itself.

Something like this:

```
<table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="500" height="70" bgcolor="#959595">
your sign-off text here
    </td>
    <td width="100" height="70"  bgcolor="#757575">
<img src=""... style="display:block;">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="600" height="70" colspan="2" bgcolor="#252525">
footer
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```